# How to check if table is already has a where clause in Laravel Query Builder?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

[Here](https://gist.github.com/goranprijic/c578acb0086e8cd85179) is an example of how can we detect if a table is already joined in a query in Laravel or not.

```
public static function isJoined($query, $table)
    {
        $joins = $query->getQuery()->joins;
        if($joins == null) {
            return false;
        }

        foreach ($joins as $join) {
            if ($join->table == $table) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

What I need is to extract the `where` clauses in a query.

I have a query that has some `join` and some `where` conditions, I need to use one of those `where` conditions in a nested select.

Now what I need is to extract that where clause from the query and use it once more. The question is how can I determine does my query contains any `where` condition on a specific column of a table (e.g. `org.id`) in my Eloquent query or not?

I tried to extract the `wheres` from query as follows but was not like what we have for joins

```
$wheres = $query->getQuery()->wheres;
  foreach ($wheres as $where) {
    dd(array_keys($where));
  }
```

And what I received is:

```
array:3 [
  0 => "type"
  1 => "query"
  2 => "boolean"
]
```

The value of `type` is `nested` and if I try the following code:

```
$wheres = $query->getQuery()->wheres;
  foreach ($wheres as $where) {
     dd($where['query']->wheres);
  }
```

Then I have:

```
array:1 [
  0 => array:5 [
    "type" => "Basic"
    "column" => "org.path"
    "operator" => "LIKE"
    "value" => "/202001/10000000/12400000%"
    "boolean" => "and"
  ]
]
```

Now why the first `wheres` return different object? I expected this result in the first `$where`!

Comment: This is the type of question you ask only when you have gotten to a certain level ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my recursive function that can be placed in a Model class:

```php
    /**
     * Returns the where conditions on a specific joined table?
     * @return array of wheres 
     */
    protected function wheres($query, $table){ 
        $conditions = [];
        if($query instanceof \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder){
            $wheres = $query->getQuery()->wheres;
        } elseif($query instanceof \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder) {
            $wheres = $query->wheres;
        }

        if($wheres == null) {
            return [];
        }

        foreach ($wheres as $where) {
            if (isset($where['column']) && substr_compare($where['column'], $table, 0, strlen($table)) === 0){
                array_push($conditions, $where);
            } else if (isset($where['query'])){
                $conditions = array_merge($conditions, $this->wheres($where['query'], $table));
            }
        }
        return $conditions;
    }
```

It can be called in the controllers like the following:

```php
$wheres = $this->wheres($query, 'org');
foreach($wheres as $where){
   ....
}
```

Comment: well since you used my idea, maybe you could upvote it :)

Comment: sure. I edited your answer and wanted after approving the edit accept the answer but as it was rejected I provided a clear and fully tested answer here.

Answer (score 2):

You can do pretty much the same with the `->wheres` property of the query builder.
It will contain an array of where clauses in the following format:

```
    ["type"] => string(5) "Basic"
    ["column"] =>string(1) "q"
    ["operator"] => string(1) "="
    ["value"] => int(2)
    ["boolean"] => string(3) "and"
```

From this, looks like the *column* property is what you could use.

UPD: Basically you could create a recursive function that will check it for you:

```
  ...
  $wheres = $query->getQuery()->wheres;
  foreach ($wheres as $where) {
     if( $checkColumn($where, 'myColumn) ) { 
        // found it
        break;
     }
  }

  function checkColumn($where, $column) {
     if( $where['type'] == 'nested' ) {
         return checkColumn($where['query'], $column);
     }
     else {
        return $where['column'] == $column;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I tried it already. Someone edited my question and removed that part. You can see what I get from `wheres`!

Comment: have you tried printing the values, not the keys? You're also printing only the first where, try seeing all of them (use var_dump instead of dd).

Comment: Only one element exist in the first wheres.

Comment: the query is a big query object and the type is `nested`

Comment: I think you can check that query to understand if the columns you need are there.

Comment: Please check the question again. I added more data.

Comment: Yeah so you have nested wheres. You can just check the `column` property of the 2nd-level where.

Comment: The question is how deep I have to extract `wheres` arrays? I mean in a general manner.

Comment: if you want write a general function like what I mentioned for joins and then I will accept the answer.

Comment: @MahdiJ.Ansari added a code example with a general solution for you

Comment: Sorry I edited your answer but it was not accepted. So I had to provide my expected answer.

Comment: This answer solved a 2hr problem -Thanks `$wheres = $query->getQuery()->wheres;`